# Defining var in one function to apply in other functions

Tags: javascript, variables, naming-conventions

This may seem like a very simple question.

I want to define a variable in one function to apply in other functions.

```
<a onclick="Alpha()" > Something </a>
<a onclick="Beta()" > Something else </a>

<script>
<script>
function Alpha() {
var x = document.getElementById('a');
```

here I want to write something like goto function Open() with the variable defined but don't exactly know how. And I want to make it so function Beta() also defines x but as something else

```
<script> 
function Open()
{
if (x.style.display === 'block')
{x.style.display = "none";}
else
{x.style.display = "block":}
}
</script>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `Open(x);` you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 possibilities:

1.make it global:

```
var yourglobvar="val";
function one(){alert(yourglobalvar);}
function two(){alert(yourglobalvar)};
```

You can even do this inside of a function ( window.globalvar ="val").

2.pass it:

```
function one(){
 var t="a";
two(t);
}

function two(u){
 alert(u)//"a"
}
```

3. even better than one, create our own higer scope:

   (function(){
    var yourvar;
    function one(){}
    function two(){}
    })()

Its better then one because it doesnt fill the global scope (wich is bad).